# Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql MySqlGeometry, EntityframeworkCore Migrations failed

Tags: mysql, geometry, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

This is a simple case of use dotnet-ef migration tool to generate the MySQL database.

I have Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql as the MySQL DB connector and class property:

```
public MySqlGeometry Location { get; set; }
```

The MySqlGeometry datatype supported by Mysql.Data.Types come with Pomelo package.

When I run

```
> dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

I get the following error:

> No suitable constructor found for entity type 'MySqlGeometry'. The
>   following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to
>   properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'bytes' in
>   'MySqlGeometry(byte[] bytes)'.

I guess the mysql geometry data type not supported by Pomelo connector? Or EntityframeworkCore Migrations tools doesn't support the MySQLGeometry data type? Or I miss any datatype package to support it.

Answer (score 0):

While `MySqlGeometry` is supported by MySqlConnector (the underlying library used by Pomelo), it is not yet supported by Pomelo itself.

We have spatial data type support planned as a feature for the `3.1.0` release.